# How to make react-native app build from two package.json?

Tags: react-native, package.json

I am building a mobile app and a web app sharing the same react-native code. 
 My problem is that the web part of the project needs the version 5 of `babel-preset-react-native` whereas the mobile part needs the `version 4.0.0`. 
 I can't put this dependency twice in my package.json (I have one package.json). 
 So how can I organize my app to run the two versions of `babel-preset-react-native` and make my app building from two package.json ? 
Have you any idea please  ?